# how to connect a zend app to mongodb database?

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am new to mongodb. I am working on Zend framework. My zend application is currently connected to mysql. I want to connect it with mongodb. I have successfully created a mongodb database and a collection. Now I need to link it with my application? Any help will be appreciated.

```
 /*return array(
 'db' => array(
     'driver'         => 'Pdo',
     'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2;host=localhost',
     'driver_options' => array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
     ),
 ),

 'service_manager' => array(
     'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                 => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
     ),
 ),
 );
*/
 use Mongo;
 use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\MongoDB;
 use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\MongoDBOptions;
 use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

 $mongo = new Mongo();
 $options = new MongoDBOptions(array(
'database'   => 'posts',
'collection' => 'posts',
 ));
 $saveHandler = new MongoDB($mongo, $options);
  $manager     = new SessionManager();
  $manager->setSaveHandler($saveHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating a mongo client in your app, provide the hostname and port.
That's all you need to connect to mongo :)

Comment: In which file i will give the host name and port??

Comment: something like this  $mongo = new Mongo('localhost');